# How to count only certain hours between the date difference?

Tags: python, datetime

Here while calculating the difference between dt1 and dt2, I want to count only 7hr from each day. How can I do it?

```
  from datetime import datetime
  def get_total_hours():
      dt1 = some_datetime # datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 25, 18, 4, 4, 204105)
      dt2 = datetime.now() # will always be now
      total_secs = (dt2 - dt1).total_seconds() 
      hours =  total_secs // 3600 
      return hours
```

Comment: Add sample input and expected result plz

Comment: Suppose `dt1` is `2022-07-10T20:31:19` and `now()` is `2022-07-11T01:46:31`.  Do you subtract 14 hours because there are two different days, or 7 hours, or 0 hours because the total interval is less than 24 hours?  What if `now()` is `2022-07-11T03:31:19`?  That's a gap of 7 hours; do you subtract 7 hours from it?  What if `now()` is `2022-07-11T19:45:00` or `2022-07-11T20:45:00`?  What if the date from `now()` is the 12th or 13th instead of the 11th?

Comment: So, if `dt1` is `2022-07-23T08:00:00` and `now()` is `2022-07-23T16:00:00`, you want the result to be 1 hour?  What about if `now()` is `2022-07-24T16:00:00`?

Comment: Computers don't like "something like" — they will produce randomly awful answers given half a chance.  You must specify exactly what you want to happen.  You have to consider the edge cases.  That is the hard part of programming — working out the precise requirements.

Comment: Yeah, well — I don't know what that really means.  You've not presented a table of required results, a series of `dt1` and `dt2` values and the result you want for each.  Suppose you have `dt1` as `2022-07-06T10:00:00` and `dt2` as `2022-07-06T12:00:00`.  The difference is 2 hours; so subtracting 7 gives a negative interval of 5 hours — is that what you want?  Yes, you really (_really_) have to think.  Time calculations are hard.  Vague specifications make them really hard.  What happens about weekends?  Public holidays?  Company holidays?  (One plausible answer is "they are ignored".)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using math. Get the number of days since d1 til d2 and remove 7 * (number of days) Like that:

```
  from datetime import datetime
  def get_total_hours():
      dt1 = some_datetime
      dt2 = datetime.now() # will always be now
      subtracted_hours = (dt2.date() - dt1.date()).days * 7
      total_secs = (dt2 - dt1).total_seconds() 
      hours =  total_secs - subtracted_hours * 3600
      return hours
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `timedelta` to specify the time you want to add or subtract to your `datetime` object..

Here is an example of how to do it

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> current_time = datetime.now()
>>> current_time
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 28, 10, 17, 17, 618890)
>>> time_diff = current_time - timedelta(hours=7)
>>> time_diff
datetime.datetime(2022, 7, 28, 3, 17, 17, 618890)
```

Read more about `timedelta` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

Comment: Can you update your question with expected input/output as well.